# Button background color doesnot changes when clicked on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, button

I created a small project in vue js to understand how class bind works and the tried to add function to each button component, so when button clicked it will change the color or background color of the button, instead of 'black'  it will show some other colors.
For now when I clicked on the 'black mode' button, the button does not change any colors but its the background ( outside the button) color changes and I don't want this behavior.
Any Help Will be much Appreciated!!!

My Button Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="btn1">
      <button
        v-on="$listeners"
        :class="[dark ? 'dark' : 'light', 'baseButton']"
        class="btn"
      >
        {{ buttonText }}
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "DynamicButton",

  props: {
    buttonText: {
      type: String,
      default: "label",
    },
    dark: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },

    light: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.baseButton {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

.light {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.dark {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.btn {
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
 
    <DynamicButton
      buttonText="Dark Mode"
      :dark="true"
      @click="handleDarkMode"
      :style="{
        backgroundColor: active ? 'red' : 'blue',
      }"
    />
    <!-- default is the light mode so we dont have to pass any pops to it-->
    <DynamicButton buttonText="Light Mode" @click="handleLightMode" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import DynamicButton from "./components/DynamicButton.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    DynamicButton,
  },

  props: {
    darkColorChange: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    lightColorChange: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleDarkMode() {
      console.log("Dark-mode clicked");
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      // this.darkColorChange.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      this.active = !this.active;
    },

    handleLightMode() {
      console.log("Light-mode clicked");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can this be helpful?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img
      alt="Vue logo"
      src="./assets/logo.png"
    />
    <HelloWorld msg="Dynamic Button Component" />

    <DynamicButton
      buttonText="Dark Mode"
      :dark="true"
      @click="handleDarkMode"
      :color="active1 ? 'red' : 'blue'"
    />
    <!-- default is the light mode so we dont have to pass any pops to it-->
    <DynamicButton
      buttonText="Light Mode"
      @click="handleLightMode"
      :color="active2 ? this.color : '#16a085'"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import DynamicButton from "./components/DynamicButton.vue";

/**************************************************************************************
 * Watch: Vue.js - Dynamic & Reusable Button Component In Vue.js
 * https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Evw5h_1Ko8
 *
 * Render class bases on PROPS , dynamic class on button by binding class and pass an array
 *
 * Using the $listeners property, you can forward all event listeners on
 * the component to a specific child element with v-on="$listeners"
 *
 * check issues I had : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74643295/button-background-color-doesnot-changes-when-clicked-on-it/74643605?noredirect=1#comment131784986_74643605
 ***************************************************************************************/

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    DynamicButton,
  },

  props: {
    // darkColorChange: {
    //   type: String,
    //   default: "",
    // },
    // lightColorChange: {
    //   type: String,
    //   default: "",
    // },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      active1: true,
      active2: true,
      color: "#3aa1b6",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleDarkMode() {
      console.log("Dark-mode clicked");
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      // this.darkColorChange.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
      this.active1 = !this.active1;
    },

    handleLightMode() {
      console.log("Light-mode clicked");
      this.active2 = !this.active2;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

---

You need pass the `active` prop to `DynamicButton` component, and bind

```
:style="{
  backgroundColor: active ? 'red' : 'blue',
}"
```

to `button`

Comment: Thanks and it works but the issue is if I do the way you suggested then both of my `<DynamicButton />` component will have the same colors and that I don't want: I want that each button should have different colors when clicked.
` <button
        v-on="$listeners"
        :class="[dark ? 'dark' : 'light', 'baseButton']"
        class="btn"
        :style="{
          backgroundColor: active ? 'black' : 'green',
        }"
      >
        {{ buttonText }}
      </button>`
// added this to the props:  
`active: { type: Boolean, default: false,`

Comment: Consider pass `color` as prop to `DynamicButton`, then you can control the color separate.

Comment: Thanks again, I created a color props in my DynamicButton component and inside template binded it with style  `:style="{ backgroundColor: color }" `,  then passing the  colors props as :  ` <DynamicButton  buttonText="Light Mode" @click="handleLightMode" :color="active ? this.color : '#16a085'"  />`
and function as this:
handleLightMode() {console.log("Light-mode clicked"); this.active = !this.active; },
Similar way for other  ` <DynamicButton />  `, Its works but now issue is when I click on one button the other button also changes it background sametime :(  Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you provide a repo for debug?

Comment: Here is the github repo: https://github.com/AyeshaAzam/dynamic-button-bgcolor